# How can I pass values from one form to another in Asp.net

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, visual-studio

How can I pass values from one form to another in Asp.net?

Can you please give me an example?

---

I got it. Thanks for everyone for replying.

In source i have to write

```
protected void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Session["name"] = textBox.Text;
    Server.Transfer("WebForm1.aspx");
}
```

and in target i have to write

```
void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    answer.Text = Session["name"].ToString();
    Session.Remove("name");
}
```

Comment: can you be a bit more specific?

Comment: I am developping asp.net application. I have 2 pages called default.aspx and another one. If I type something in a text box of Defalut.aspx, It should display in second page.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Client side technology:
1)Query String
2)Cookies

Query String:
For SEnding:

`string name="abc"; Response.Redirect(" Page2.aspx?name= "+name);`

For Getting:
On Page2.aspx 
`string name=Response.QueryString.GetValue(" name ");`

For cookies you can use
Sending:
 `HttpCookie h=new HttpCookie();
h.Name="name";
h.Value="abc";
Response.Cookies.Add(h) ;`

Getting:
`string name = Request.Cookies('name');`

Server Side Technology:
1)Session

For Setting:
`Session["Name"] = "Abc";`

For Getting:
`string str = Session["Name"].ToString();`

In Session you can pass any object type.