# how can I transfer data from a webpage to another one in asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, query-string

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I pass values from one form to another in Asp.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6746860/how-can-i-pass-values-from-one-form-to-another-in-asp-net)

Hi.

I want to pass some **data** from **one page to another** at **asp.net** how can I do this in **asp.net**?

Comment: I cannot understand why are you decreasing my rep?

Comment: Because while asking a question on stackoverflow you should do some basic search about your problem and if you don't find any solution, then you have to ask here. Asking similar questions which are already there in stackoverflow leads to the waste of time.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `QueryString`, `Session`, or `Cookies`

Note. In all cases when reading the value from the corresponding collection, you need to validate if the object exists before consuming it. (check for null)

### Using the query string

#### Page 1

```
<a href="mysecondPage.aspx?customerID=43" >My Link</a>
```

#### Page 2

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var c = this.Request.QueryString["customerID"];
    }
```

### Using the Session object

#### Page 1

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Session["customerID"] = 44;
    }
```

#### Page 2

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var c = (int)this.Session["customerID"];
    }
```

### Using cookies

#### Page 1

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Response.Cookies["customerID"].Value = "43";
    }
```

#### Page 2

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var c = int.Parse(this.Request.Cookies["customerID"].Value);
    }
```