# How can I pass variables or values from one asp.net vb.net code page to another?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, variables, transfer

I have a site/portal created in ASP.net and VB.net.

I want to know how to reference variables between two asp pages, but not the pages themselves, I want to directly transfer data from the .aspx.vb bit of the page to another pages .aspx.vb file. Is that possible?

Comment: You could set a cookie, set a value in a shared resource (database), set a value in session, use a query string parameter when redirecting to the page.  There are a lot of options for this, but none that allow you to just access values on the page itself.

Answer (score 0):

An easy way in asp.net/VB.net is to use session variables.

```
Session("myVariable") = "blah"
```

From another .aspx.vb page you can now use this value.  Example:

```
Dim strTest as String = ""
strTest = Session("myVariable")
```

You can access this page on any of your .aspx pages for this session by referencing `Session("myVariable")`

Comment: So I could access this in one aspx.vb 'behind-page' vb form as a reference? I want to be able to set the value of a variable on one aspx.vb 'page' and only be able to update it and access the updated value from another aspx.vb 'page'.

Comment: You can set it on any page and update it from any aspx.vb page.

Answer (score 0):

if it's Not sensitive data you can do something like this,

Original page:
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)

```
{
          string MyOccupation = "Software Developer";

          string url;
          url = "page2.aspx?occupation=" + MyOccupation;

          Response.Redirect(url);

}
```

Next Page:
    string RetrievedValue;protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)

```
{

          this.TextBox1.Text = Request.QueryString["occupation"];
          RetrievedValue = this.TextBox1.Text;

}
```

taken from http://forums.asp.net/t/1223291.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Duplicate of [How can I pass values from one form to another in Asp.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6746860/how-can-i-pass-values-from-one-form-to-another-in-asp-net/6746960#6746960)

Client side technology: Query String

Query String: For SEnding:

`string name="abc"; Response.Redirect(" Page2.aspx?name= "+name);`

For Getting: `On Page2.aspx string name=Response.QueryString.GetValue(" name ");`

Server Side Technology:Session

For Setting: `Session["Name"] = "Abc";`

For Getting: `string str = Session["Name"].ToString();`

In Session you can pass any object type.

Answer (score 0):

Since nobody posted this, here is Microsoft's page about passing values between pages. It gives C# and VB examples: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6c3yckfw.aspx